# Rendering a comma separated string of values in React Native

Tags: reactjs, string, react-native, split, array.prototype.map

I am extracting {item.dosage} from a JSON which gives me the following string

```
"300gr short pasta, 2 spring onions, 50gr parmesan cheese"
```

and I'd like to show it each ingredient separated by comma in a separate text line like this

```
   300gr short pasta
   2 spring onions
   50gr parmesan cheese
```

I was trying to do the following within my JSX

```
{item.dosage.map((step, i) => (
        <Text>
            {i > 0 && ", "}
               {step}
        </Text>
 ))}
```

and I'm getting an error about "undefined is not a function...".

Comment: what is dosage? what is it contains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const str = "300gr short pasta, 2 spring onions, 50gr parmesan cheese"

...
<Text>
  {str.split(',').map((step)=> <Text>{step}{",\n"}</Text>)}
</Text>
...

// so try this way
<Text>
 {item.dosage.split(',').map((step)=> <Text>{step}{",\n"}</Text>)}
</Text>
```

Comment: it worked although I needed to adjust slightly the code with `split(", ")` and `{"\n"}`. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

in the first sight, it looks like that is getting close to what u look for
this way u can give margins to the View as desired..

```
{item.dosage.split(', ').map((step, i) => (
  <View>
      <Text>
        {i > 0 && ", "}

         {step}
      </Text>
  </View>
 ))}
```

Comment: your solution does not seem to be working, it is still showing as a full string without comma separation.

Comment: what does `item.dosage` contains.? i have edited solution

Comment: it is commented in the first line of this post `"300gr short pasta, 2 spring onions, 50gr parmesan cheese"`